# Two images on top of another with PhotoView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-photoview

I'm using the PhotoView component from [here](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) because I want to zoom and move my image. But I would like to have several other (smaller) images on top of this image at different positions. Like this:

```
+----------------------------------+ 
|                                  |
|  +------+                        |
|  |Image2|                        |
|  +------+                        |
|             Image1               |
|                                  |
|           +------+               |
|           |Image3|               |
|           +------+               |
|                                  |
+----------------------------------+
```

If the bigger background image is zoomed in, the other images will zoom in as well and also move with the image. Is this possible with this component and if so, how?

Comment: see [PatchworkDrawable](https://github.com/pskink/PatchworkDrawable)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have changed my PhotoView to a [SubsamplingScaleImageView](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view). Since this also supports zooming and panning, this one fits my needs.

Comment: is it still `ImageView`? if so, there is no difference what custom `ImageView` you are using